# Como Buscar Datos Que no Coincidan MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

tengo dos tablas en la tabla "a" tengo todo el universo de registros y en la tabla "b" unos cuantos
entonces necesito consultar los datos que no encuentran en la tabla "b" y que si están en la tabla "a", las tablas con las siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la tabla "b" es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el resultado esperado seria los dos ultimo registros de la tabla "a" como debería formular la consulta mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from tablaA
where codigo_A not in
(select codigo_B
 from tablaB)
```

Debes hacer una subconsulta. Aquí mediante el **operador not in** obtenemos todos los registros de la **tabla A** cuyo código no está incluido en los códigos de la **tabla B**.

Comment: era justo lo que estaba buscando el volumen de datos que manejo es de unos 38000 registros. pensé que podría necesitar un INNER JOIN

Answer (score 0):

Otra solucion posible es:

```
select a.*
from tablaA a
left join tablaB b on b.codigo_B = a.codigo_A
where b.id_b is null;
```

no se el volumen de datos que manejas, pero los joins suelen ser mas eficientes que los not in.